# How to include additional compiler options"includes" and "include-libraries"?

Tags: apache-flex

How i can include the additional compiler options "includes" or "include-libraries"? I want to include a class named myClass or the package assets. So i want exactly what i must declare in the additional compiler arguments area. Thanks!

Comment: There is no compiler option named `includes` and `include-libraries` is not used for including classes. Also, what do you mean with 'package assets'? All the classes in a certain package? Or something else?

Comment: I just look on http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html and the package assets is a certain package. How a can i include a certain class or package?

Comment: My apologies: `includes` does seem to exist. Is this an application or a library you're compiling? I'm asking because when compiling an application all classes on the source path are automatically added. Do you want to add other classes than that?

Comment: @RIAstar One of us is mistaken. I believe when compiling an application, unused classes in the source path are not added into the final SWF build. This is routinely seen when Value Objects are never accessed directly in code; but the server does return an array of them; and the end result is that the AMF Server side object to client side object translation is not working.  ( The reason for this is that the object class was not in the final SWF because it was optimized out ).

Comment: @www.Flextras.com That's correct. I just didn't want to go into that level of detail yet before I knew exactly what the OP was asking for. I must say I never thought of using `includes` to solve this particular issue (not in the least because I didn't know that it existed). Also I'm not really certain that it _will_ solve that issue.

Comment: So, how can i use it? For instance, if I had to import a package named "myPackage" or a single class "MyClass", what should I declare?

Comment: Ok! I have partially solved the problem!                            For including a single class, i just declare...                        `-includes myPackage.MyClass`                                           and it work!

Comment: Now i want to include the whole package MyPackage but, using the `include-libraries` option i have some problems! I will update you!