# How to include all calsses with additional compiler options in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include additional compiler options“includes” and “include-libraries”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170503/how-to-include-additional-compiler-optionsincludes-and-include-libraries)

I want to include in my flex project a custom package that contains hundreds of fxg objects using the additional compiler options. Which specific option can i use an how i should I declare?

Comment: I believe I've asked you this before: is it a library or an application project? (Also you shouldn't repeat your questions; if your initial question was unclear, you should rather edit that one).

Comment: I don't understand why this is different than the previous question you asked on the same topic, so I voted to close.

Comment: My last question was partly solved by me using the `includes` option for include a single class. But if i want to import a whole package using the `include-libraries`, it doesn't work. So I asked a new question to draw attention to my issue. In my last question I have had feedback but without much help.No offense to you. I have to solve the problem.

Comment: You complain that I repeat the same questions but no one has been more help to me!

Answer (score 0):

-includes for MXMLC and -includes-classes for COMPC.

Comment: `includes` works fine with one or more classes. But my problem is to import a whole package in one time with `include-libraries`option. For instance if i declare `-include-libraries myPackage` doesn't work. Maybe i wrong the definition of the path name but i don't now. I would like a practical example of declaring an include-libraries. Thanks